# PyInstaller - No console executable with outputs

Tags: python, c#, process, pyinstaller

I have a .NET application that needs to:

- Run an executable file that is created in Python
- Read the outputs of this executable (such as status messages, exit codes and exception messages)

The major question here is how to use PyInstaller + Python to create an `.exe` file that has readable outputs without a console.

### So, main questions:

Is this possible using PyInstaller with **no console**?

- How can my python script `.exe` make an output that is accessible to the caller application?

  - Are there more than one type of output or just console outputs? (writing files is a possibility, but not the greatest solution here)
- How can a C# application read these outputs? I guess `System.Diagnosis.Process` can handle this?

#### Very newbie question:

- What does PyInstaller run from my script? Does a `.py` file already start with commands or should I have some `__main__` function or something like that?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to read output from a process when there is no `stdout`  to write to.  I suppose you could send it through a network socket stream of some kind.  I don't really know what you are asking in your other question.